# Blazor Server and CleanCode - ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-identity

I am having trouble wiring up identity into Blazor server with ASP.NET Core identity. Specifically getting the correct logged in state in Blazor pages (while I am getting them from the Blazor pages).

I think it's related to some of the startup being initialized in another project - but not sure how to debug it or what the solution is to be able to get the logged in state correctly.

Reproduction steps and link to GH repo below as a POC.

**Background**

I'm porting over the [clean-code](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture) project by [JasonTaylor](https://github.com/jasontaylordev) from Angular / ASP.NET Core to a Blazor server project with ASP.NET Core Identity.

**Issue**

The application runs up and I can browse the pages when I register I can see logged-in state in the identity-based default pages but in the Blazor pages that use the `AuthorizeView` (e.g. `LoginDisplay.razor`) it's not aware of being authorized.

Startup in the Blazor project:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplication();
        services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration);

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddSingleton<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddDbContextCheck<ApplicationDbContext>();
        
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

`AddInfrastructure` in another project references in startup:

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseInMemoryDatabase"))
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("CleanArchitectureDb"));
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));
        }

        services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());

        services.AddScoped<IDomainEventService, DomainEventService>();

        services
            .AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddTransient<IDateTime, DateTimeService>();
        services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();
        services.AddTransient<ICsvFileBuilder, CsvFileBuilder>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CanPurge", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
        });

        return services;
    }
}

public class RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<TUser>
    : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider where TUser : class
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    private readonly IdentityOptions _options;

    public RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(loggerFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

    protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
        AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Get the user manager from a new scope to ensure it fetches fresh data
        var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

        try
        {
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();
            return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (scope is IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
            {
                await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                scope.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityStampAsync(UserManager<TUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(_options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
            var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
            return principalStamp == userStamp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Register : https://localhost:44399/Identity/Account/Register
2. Browse to : https://localhost:44399/Identity/Account/Login - Notice username in header is populated from the ASP.Net Identity pages
3. Browse to : https://localhost:44399/ - Notice the Header is Register, Login, About (Based on https://github.com/davidshorter/CleanCodeBlazor/blob/Rework/src/Web/Shared/LoginDisplay.razor)

[image]

Pushed up my changes to GH if anyone fancies a
look : https://github.com/davidshorter/CleanCodeBlazor/tree/Rework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with mixing IdentityServer and ASP.net identity.

By removing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` and the use of base class from `ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>` back to `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` resolved this.